# regex matching multiple repeating groups

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s = " 3434 garbage workorders: 138 waiting, 2 running, 3 failed, 134 completed"
```

I would like to parse the statuses and counts after "workorders". I've tried the following regex:

```
r = r"workorders:( (\d+) (\w+),?)*"
```

but this only returns the last group. How can I return all groups?

p.s. I know I could do this in python, but was wondering if there's a pure regex solution

```
>>> s = " 3434 garbage workorders: 138 waiting, 2 running, 3 failed, 134 completed"
>>> r = r"workorders:( (\d+) (\w+),?)*"
>>> re.findall(r, s)
[(' 134 completed', '134', 'completed')]
>>>
```

output should be close to

```
[('138', 'waiting'), ('2', 'running'), ('3', 'failed'), ('134', 'completed')]
```

Comment: And how are you using that regex - have you used `re.findall` for instance or something else?

Comment: @JonClements yes

Comment: `138 waiting, 2 running, 3 failed, 134 completed` should be the output? Each in seperate group?

Comment: @GarbageCollector yes, so that I can do mapping 'waiting' - > 138, etc

Answer (score 2):

For the text in the example, you could try it like this:

[`(?:(\d+) (\w+)(?=,|$))+`](https://regex101.com/r/FxgdUB/1)

**Explanation**

- A non capturing group `(?:`
- A capturing group for one or more digits `(\d+)`
- A white space
- A capturing group for one or more word characters `(\w+)`
- A positive lookhead which asserts that what follows is either a comma or the end of the string `(?=,|$)`
- Close the non capturing group and repeat that one or more times `)+`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XSQKA97004)

That would give you:

`[('138', 'waiting'), ('2', 'running'), ('3', 'failed'), ('134', 'completed')]`

Answer (score 1):

this should work for your particular case:

```
re.findall('[:,] (\d+)', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I found it better to use regex after you process the string as much as possible; regex on an arbitrary string will only cause headaches.

In your case, try splitting on ':' (or even workorders:) and getting the stuff after to get only the counts of statuses. After that, it's easy to get the counts for each status.

```
s = " 3434 garbage workorders: 138 waiting, 2 running, 3 failed, 134 
      completed"
statuses = s.split(':') #['3434 garbage workorders', ' 138 waiting, 2 running, 3 failed, 134 completed']
statusesStr = ''.join(statuses[1]) # ' 138 waiting, 2 running, 3 failed, 134 completed'

statusRe = re.compile("(\d+)\s*(\w+)")
statusRe.findall(statusesStr) #[('138', 'waiting'), ('2', 'running'), ('3', 'failed'), ('134', 'completed')]
```

Edit: changed expression to meet desired outcome and more robust

Comment: If you change the pattern to `statusRe = re.compile("(\d+)\s+(\w+)")`, it'll split each number/status pair like the OP wants.

Comment: Ah oops, I had that  (-ish) initially but saw the comment under the question that had a different output. Edited, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer that will only look at regex that are after `:`

```
 re.findall(r'(?: )\d+ \w+')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your output exactly.

```
map = re.findall(r'(\d+) ([A-Za-z]+)', s.split("workorders:")[1])
```

You can then bust this init.

```
x = {v: int(k) for k, v in map}
```